# Tree view component in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tree, treeview, treeviewitem

I want to integrate tree view in my React Native application:
[image: Tree View]

I referred below plugins for that

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-final-tree-view
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-tree-view

But it does not fulfill my requirement as I share image. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can check this  :https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en-GB

Comment: @Jagroop I am not asking chrome tool and i am asking about code level how i can integrate in React native mobile application